# Find in mongodb (search in the first 30 records)

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

how do I make an appointment within 30 mongo documents?

## Ex:

```
db.find (). count () = 100 documents //my base
```

## I wanted

```
db.find ({$ {and 'user.gender': 'Male'}, {'in first 30 records "}) = 5 documents
```

## it is not

```
db.find ({'user.gender': 'Male'}). limit (30) = 30 documents //I do not want it
```

Comment: Do you have a field for sorting your records like timestamp, integerid or smt?

Comment: yes User data: registration date, gender, id ...

Comment: can you try something like this `db.find({'user.gender': 'Male'}).sort({'user.registrationdate':1}).limit(30);` you can use -1 for descending sort.

Comment: It is still not this, imagine an array (m, m, f, f, m, m) I want the first 3 records, only items = f, total = 1
the first three items:
item 1 = m: not
item 2 = m: not
item 3 = F: yes

#item 4 .... ignore

Comment: your question still unclear. can you show us your document with expected output? also you need to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is simple, eg (1 = a, 2 = a, b = 3, b = 4, 5 = c), I want a query that in the top 3 shows how many items are equal to "a", the answer in this example is 2, because the item 1 and item 2 is equal to "a" but the third is different and the rest I do not count for my query is the item 1-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `$aggregate` in `mongodb`

for eg

```
db.collName.aggregate([     
    { $limit: 30 },
    { $match: { 'user.gender': 'Male'} }
])
```

If you want to sort the collection on basics of any field you can use the `$sort` in the `aggregation pipeline`.

Also please do remember the **fact** that "there is no guarantee that your documents are returned in any particular order by a query as long as you don't sort explicitly. Documents in a new collection are usually returned in insertion order, but various things can cause that order to change unexpectedly, so don't rely on it.

When you sort by `_id` field the items are returned by creation Date. So you can also `sort` by `_id` first and then limit your documents.

For eg:

```
db.collName.aggregate([
        { $sort: { _id: 1 } },                 
        { $limit: 30 },
        { $match: { 'user.gender': 'Male'} }
    ])
```

Explaination:

It will first `sort` your documents based on the `_id` field in documents and then `limit` your documents to 30 and then find a `match`on the returned documents based on the query.